# Is there are way to add two different color Iphone x SafeArea on Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, iphone-x, safeareaview

I would like to know is there any way to add two different colors to iPhone X SafeArea?

On `React Native` this can be fixed by adding two `SafeAreaView`. Does anyone know how to fix this one on flutter?

Thanks

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.blue,
      child: SafeArea(
        left: true,
        top: true,
        right: true,
        bottom: true,
        child: Scaffold(
          resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text(widget.title),
          ),
          body: Center(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  'You have pushed the button this many times:',
                ),
                Text(
                  '$_counter',
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: _incrementCounter,
            tooltip: 'Increment',
            child: Icon(Icons.add),
          ), 
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Two different colors as a gradient or top safe area with a different color and bottom safe area with a different color?

Comment: i wanna add Top Safearea with different color and bottom Safearea with different color.

Comment: There is only one SafeArea widget in the code you shared. Can you please add any missing code and explain in a more abstract way what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Please find the below answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do one simple thing => Mark top property of `SafeArea` to **false** so the top area of the phone will take the background color of the `AppBar` and the bottom SafeArea will take the color of the parent `container`. Ideally, I would suggest if you are bounding your `scaffold` inside `SafeArea` then it's top `SafeArea` color should be the same as `AppBar` background color and bottom SafeArea color is as per your requirement(parent container's color).

I modified your code with two different colors:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.blue,
      child: SafeArea(
        top: false,        
        child: Scaffold(
          resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
          appBar: AppBar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.orange,
            title: Text(widget.title),
          ),
          body: Center(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  'You have pushed the button this many times:',
                ),
                Text(
                  '$_counter',
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: _incrementCounter,
            tooltip: 'Increment',
            child: Icon(Icons.add),
          ), 
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

**Option 2:** If you are using a scaffold then you can simply bind your body widget inside and it will fix your problem.

Comment: This is so useful! Thank you very much!

Comment: but the issue raise when we use Colors.white. It shows some elevation, how to remove that elevatiaon?

Answer (score 1):

In SafeArea widget, we have some elements like bottom, top,...

if set bottom = true, SafeArea will include bottom. Do respectively with top element.

To get the height of bottom/top area, you can reach by this way `MediaQuery.of(context).padding.bottom`.

To make some background colors for bottom/top area, you can add a Container widget which have a height as above.

Answer (score 1):

So, i find this method to do that. You can change static colors, i did that for example. I don't know is it right method, but it works. I think that @dhaval-kansara's method is not what i wanted, because status bar is transparent and on scroll it overflows. I accept criticism in my address, as I am still a beginner and may not know a lot. (sorry for my english)

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    
    class ColoredSafeArea extends StatelessWidget {
      final Color topColor;
      final Color bottomColor;
      final Color color;
      final Widget child;
    
      const ColoredSafeArea(
          {Key key,
          this.topColor,
          this.bottomColor,
          this.color,
          @required this.child,})
          : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return ColoredBox(
          color: bottomColor ?? Colors.yellow, // bottombar color
          child: SafeArea(
            top: false,
            child: ColoredBox(
              color: topColor ?? Colors.blue, // statusbar color
              child: SafeArea(
                top: true,
                child: ColoredBox(
                  color: color ?? Colors.teal, // background color
                  child: child,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

just **wrap SafeArea** in a styled container
[image]

```
return Scaffold(
  body: Container(
    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
      image: DecorationImage(
        image: AssetImage('assets/images/backgrounds/path'),
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
      ),
    ),
    child: SafeArea(
      child: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: [],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```